# How to use MercurialEclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I have been using the built in mercurial support in NetBeans for a while now and its great. I just recently installed MercurialEclipse from http://cbes.javaforge.com/update so I can start using Mercurial for my Flex projects as well.

I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

I watched the video, when I right click files in the Package Explorer and go to tools I only have 2 or 3 options: Apply Patch, Share Project [, Show Local History]

When I click show local history, it says:

> No local history for selected resource.

My project is a repository and I have made some changes since the last commit. I would like to see a diff of those changes so I can review them before committing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to click "Share Project" and enable Mercurial support for this project.